# Unable to find the coordinates of the pressed buttons

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

only problem is that whenever i set initial value for the x and y to be greater than 10,it gives bad result.Please help.It works fine for the values less than 10 for x and y.
i have also debugged it and find out whenever the button is pressed after the 10th index it behaves like setting the variable i to 1.i am unable to fix this issue as i am new in java.so i really need help in this.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

class butMaddFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
int x=12;
int y=12;
  JButton[][] buttons = new JButton[x][y];
    JPanel mPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel bPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel cPanel = new JPanel();
    JTextArea scoreKeeper = new JTextArea();
    Container c = getContentPane();
    int[][] intArray = new int[x][y];

    public butMaddFrame()
    {
        butGen();
        score2();
        //cPanel.add(scoreKeeper);
        bPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(x,y));
        mPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        mPanel.add(bPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      //  mPanel.add(cPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        c.add(mPanel);

        setTitle("ButtonMaddness");
        setSize(1000,400);
        setLocation(200,200);
   setVisible(true);
    }

    private void butGen()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<y;j++)
            {
                buttons[i][j] = new JButton(String.valueOf(i)+"x"+String.valueOf(j));
               buttons[i][j].setActionCommand("button" +i +"_" +j);
                buttons[i][j].addActionListener(this);
                bPanel.add(buttons[i][j]);
            }
    }

    private void score()
    {
  //      String string = "";
    //    for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
      //  {
        //    for(int j=0;j<y;j++)
              //  string += i+"x"+j+" => " +String.valueOf(intArray[i][j]) +"\t";
           // string+= "\n";
       // }
      //  scoreKeeper.setText(string);

        }

    private void score2()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<y;j++)
                buttons[i][j].setText(String.valueOf(intArray[i][j]));


        }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getActionCommand().contains("button"))
        {
            int i =    Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(e.getActionCommand().replaceAll("button","").replaceAll        ("_", "").charAt(0)));
            int j =    Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(e.getActionCommand().replaceAll("button","").replaceAll           ("_", "").charAt(1)));

            intArray[i][j]++;
           // buttons[i][j].setVisible(false);


            buttons[i][j].setBackground(Color.black);



       System.out.println(e.getActionCommand() +"  " +i +"  " +j);
        }
     //   score2();
    }
}




 import java.awt.*;
 import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
   public class buttonMaddness {
 public static void main(String[] args)
     {
            butMaddFrame myFrame = new butMaddFrame();
            myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
replaceAll("_", "").charAt(0)
```

because some of your buttons have things like 11_9 for
example. So you get just the first 1 of the number 11.

Just change your actionPerformed method 
to this and your bug will be fixed.

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getActionCommand().contains("button")) {

            String str = e.getActionCommand().replaceAll("button", "");
            System.out.println(str);
            String[] v = str.split("_");
            int i = Integer.parseInt(v[0]);
            int j = Integer.parseInt(v[1]);
            /*
            int i = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(e.getActionCommand()
                    .replaceAll("button", "").replaceAll("_", "").charAt(0)));
            int j = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(e.getActionCommand()
                    .replaceAll("button", "").replaceAll("_", "").charAt(1)));
             */

            intArray[i][j]++;
            // buttons[i][j].setVisible(false);

            buttons[i][j].setBackground(Color.black);

            System.out.println(e.getActionCommand() + "  " + i + "  " + j);
        }
        // score2();
    }
```

Comment: +1, I like the addition of the System.out.println(...) to demonstrate what the value of the string is after you strip out "button". It should now be obvious to the OP that when you use the charAt(..) method you will only get a single character when in fact there are 4 characters in the string.

Comment: @camickr Well, I added it so that it becomes obvious for me :) but yes, this is the side-effect, I guess.

Comment: `I added it so that it becomes obvious for me :)` because you naturally do this to aid in debugging, which is a good thing :) The OP, being new to Java, tried to write all the code in one step to assign the values to "I" and "j". This causes a problem because you can't display temporary values. It is almost always better to break code down into multiple statements so you can see the values at each step of the process. Hopefully the OP will remember this debugging technique for the future.